# Expand and collapse accordion based on checked radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to open or close the tab on Accordion based on the checked value from a button group above.

In my application, there is a Page Reload everytime I select radio button.

For example: if I select 1, then Collapsible Group # 1 will open, if I select radio button # 2, then Collapsible Group Item # 2 will open.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[name='inlineRadioOptions']").click(function () {
        var checkedValue = $("input[name='inlineRadioOptions']:checked").val();
        console.log(checkedValue);
        if (checkedValue == "option1") {
            $("#collapseOne").collapse('show');
            $("#collapseTwo").collapse('hide');
        } else if (checkedValue == "option2") {
            $("#collapseOne").collapse('hide');
            $("#collapseTwo").collapse('show');

        } else {
            console.log("Oops.");
        }
    });
});
```

[This is my jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xw3nhmgy/9/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JS in the fiddle does not match what you say in the question. You need to change `graduate` to `option2` in the `else if`:
https://jsfiddle.net/z49fxn6q/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("input[name='inlineRadioOptions']").click(function () {
        var checkedValue = $("input[name='inlineRadioOptions']:checked").val();
        console.log(checkedValue);
        if (checkedValue == "option1") {
            $("#collapseOne").collapse('show');
            $("#collapseTwo").collapse('hide');
        } else if (checkedValue == "option2") {
            $("#collapseOne").collapse('hide');
            $("#collapseTwo").collapse('show');

        } else {
            console.log("Oops.");
        }
    });
});
```